# which distro has thumbnails in file upload

Tags: dual-boot

is there any linux distro that shows thumbnails in file upload dialog  [image]

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You have this flagged as *windows-subsystem-for-linux*, but your question does not appear to have anything to do with that.  I've submitted an edit remove the tag, but if you really do have a question about WSL, please edit the question to address it.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the File Chooser dialog, which is used when opening or saving files.

[Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) is a good option for you, because the File Chooser can be directly adjusted with different views.

In the example below, I've selected *Icons View* ➀.

You can adjust the size of the icons by using the *Icon size* slider ➁.

[image]